# MS Word VBA - select range, check spelling and accept first suggest

Tags: vba, ms-word, range, spell-checking

i'd like to write a macro that selects the next word to the right of the cursor, checks its spelling and replaces an error with the first suggestion..

can anyone with more VBA knowledge than me (..laugh) help out.

i tried the macro recorder but did not get any farther than this:

```vb
Sub FirstSuggest()
    Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    ...
    ...

End Sub
```

thanks,
kay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```vb
Dim r As Range
Set r = Selection.GoToNext(wdGoToSpellingError)

With r.GetSpellingSuggestions()
  If .Count > 0 Then
    r.Text = .Item(1).Name
  End If
End With
```

Comment: See also https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/34652-automatic-full-document-spell-check-correction-without.html#post112057